# How do I consume query parameters from POST in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to write a route in FastAPI to consume a POST request. I have the following URL example:

```
https://URL.com/api/FlexfoneCall/outgoing?AccountId=1234&TimeStamp=2021-05-20+08%3a30%3a56&UniqueCallId=SIP%2f%2b4512345678-0000e4a81463430317&EmployeeLocalNumber=200&ANumber=12345678&BNumber=87654321&PhoneLocalNumber=123456
```

However, I'm only used to consuming the body from request. How do I "fetch" the path parameter data from the above example?

EDIT:

I'm trying to write a service that receives the above URL from an external service. I tried doing the following because I thougth that since it was a POST my route should look like this:

```
@app.post('/callout', response_model=CallIn)
async def create_call_out(callout: CallOut, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_write_call_out = write_call_out(db, callout)

    return db_write_call_out
```

With the following Pydantic model:

```
class CallOut(BaseModel):
    accountid: str = None
    timestamp: str = None
    uniquecallid: str = None
    employeelocalnumber: str = None
    anumber: str = None
    bnumber: str = None
    phonelocalnumber: str = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And CRUD function:

```
def write_call_out(db: Session, callout: CallOut):
    db_write_call_out = DBCallOut(**callout.dict())
    db.add(db_write_call_out)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_write_call_out)

    return db_write_call_out
```

SQLAlchemy ORM model for writing the query params to a SQL DB:

```
class DBCallOut(Base):
    __tablename__ = "call_out"

    accountid = Column('AccountId', String(250))
    uniquecallid = Column('UniqueCallId', String(250))
    employeelocalnumber = Column('EmployeeLocalNumber', String(250))
    anumber = Column('ANumber', String(250))
    timestamp = Column('TimeStamp', String(250))
    phonelocalnumber = Column('PhoneLocalNumber', String(250))
    bnumber = Column('BNumber', String(250))
    ID = Column(Integer,  primary_key=True,  index=True, autoincrement=True)
```

But I keep getting a 422 Error.

EDIT 2:

Ended up changing my route to the following:

```
@app.get('/call')
async def outgoing(AccountId: str,
                   TimeStamp: str,
                   UniqueCallId: str,
                   EmployeeLocalNumber: str,
                   ANumber: str,
                   BNumber: str,
                   PhoneLocalNumber: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    callout = {"AccountId": AccountId,
                "TimeStamp": TimeStamp,
                "UniqueCallId": UniqueCallId,
                "EmployeeLocalNumber": EmployeeLocalNumber,
                "ANumber": ANumber,
                "BNumber": BNumber,
                "PhoneLocalNumber": PhoneLocalNumber}
    db_write_call_out = write_call_out(db, callout)

    return db_write_call_out
```

This is working, but it's somewhat clunky.

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/ ?

Comment: unsure of what ? What have you tried ? The code in the documentaion is pretty easy

Comment: Share your actual code that handles `/api/FlexfoneCall/outgoing` please

Comment: I haven't written anything, because I'm rather confused about the type of route I need to use, and why the example is sending parameters in the URL directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to consume Path parameters (part of the url path, as in `google.co/youtube/videos/1`) or if you want to consume query parameters (a variable named after the path url, as in `google.co?video=1`) but either way you just declare the path parameters as parameters of the of the method decoration (`@app(params)`) and for query parameters you declare them in the method parameters (`def get_video(params)`).
so for the given link, if you want to get the query parameters you would do:

```
@app.post("outgoing/")
async def do_something(
      AccountId: int, 
      TimeStamp: str, 
      UniqueCallId: str, 
      EmployeeLocalNumber: str,
      ANumber: int,
      BNumber: int,
      PhoneLocalNumber: int
    ):
    # do some stuff
    save_to_db(owner=AccountId,time=TimeStamp,contact=PhoneLocalNumber)
```

and to get path variables (sticking to the example I gave above) you do this:

```
@app.post("video/{video_id}")
async def do_something():
    # do something
    save_to_db(video_id)
```

Whichever on you choose to implement will take the parameter values (by location in the path for path params, or from the query parameter by the same name in the query params) from the request url the client sends and place them into the variable names you declare. then you use them as normal like the example shows.

The docs are very newcomer friendly so for query parameters refer [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/), and for path parameters refer [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/).

as a side note, for more pythonic code, I suggest you use snake case to name your variables

Comment: For the example with `video_id` you miss the method parameters, it's SAME as query param, see https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#multiple-path-and-query-parameters

Comment: What does you request body look like @Artem? it seems you are either missing a variable or misspelling one in your POST request. if accountid is the DB key I suggest you make it an optional variable in a supper class `Callout(BaseModel)`, then inherit from it in `CallOutPost(CallOut)`  where the rest of the mandatory variables sit

Comment: @azro I intentionally left them out to avoid confusion. I made an example the *ONLY* uses path parameters so the distinction can be clear and nonconfusing

Comment: Made all variables optional in the BaseModel. Still keep getting a 422.

Comment: @ItIsEntropy If I replace the BaseModel in `create_call_out()` with the query params, the request goes through. Is the BaseModel/Pydantic model case sensitive or anything?

Comment: Yes it is. Pydantic uses JSON which is case sensitive. do you post anything in the request body? if you don't then that's your problem. you are posting information in the query params, but the `callout: CallOut` part is telling fastAPI to look for content in the request body; content which does not exist.
Edit: HTTP: 422 means that your request is valid, but semantically makes no sense, so in this case everything about your request was right, but you were asking it to parse an empty JSON request

Comment: @Artem if this answer helped you out please accept it and give an upcote. Thanks

Comment: @ItIsEntropy So yes, the request body is empty for some reason. I've updated the question with the new route that works. I think it's somewhat clunky though. Pydantic is only for the body, when I guess? Essentially, if the URL had 20 query parameters, would I then have to declare all 20 in the function?

Comment: Yes you would have to declare all 20 params cos that's the only way to consume them. and yes Pydantic is only for the body. if you are sending JSON objects to the route use it, otherwise use query or form parameters and it's not needed, also no need to make models off of its `BaseModel` class.

Comment: to use the old one simply send a JSON object to the endpoint as it was.. i find using Postman to test my requests very useful, but if you're on javascript it has a builtin JSON object so make the model, then post it with JSON stringify, thn you'll have cleaner code